# Print PDF file using Foxit Reader and C#

Tags: c#, printing, process, foxit-reader

My program prints silently via the PDF reader `Foxit Reader` in a new process.

On occasion, my program attempts to print two PDFs at the same time, which causes one of them to fail to print.

Here is my code:

```
string filename = "file.pdf";

string fileDir1 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe";

Process pdfProcess = new Process();
pdfProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileDir1;
pdfProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/t {0} {1}", filename ,"pos-80");
pdfProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
pdfProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDir1);
pdfProcess.Start();

if (!pdfProcess.WaitForExit(2500))
{
    pdfProcess.Kill();

}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm not an expert with the Foxit software, but on the surface it appears that Foxit has multi-tasking issues. To solve I would try to write a queueing system that monitors Foxit processes and only starts a new one when there are no other Foxit processes running.

Comment: thanks a lot for reply
yes , you are correct , the is issue appears because multi-tasking 
but I don't know how i can solve it.

when foxit reader print file , sometime display error 

The process cannot access the file   "file with path "   because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Foxit open.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

List<Process> Processlist = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();
```

This gives you a list of currently running processes.

```
foreach(Process p in Processlist)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process " + p.Id + " is named '" + p.ProcessName + "'");

}
```

When running the above code, you should see the name of the Foxit process in your output window.

Alternatively, put a break-point on the foreach line and hover over the list to see all the names that way.

```
bool IsFoxitProcessRunning = false;

foreach(Process p in Processlist)
{
    if(p.ProcessName == "Foxit process name here") //Replace with the name of the foxit process
    {
        IsFoxitProcessRunning  = true;

    }

}
```

Now, only start a new Foxit process if one isn't already running.

```
if(!IsFoxitProcessRunning)
{
    //insert code to run next foxit process here.

}
```

Notes:

- You may need to implement a queue to keep track of pdfs waiting to run.
- You may also wish to alert IT support if a Foxit is waiting more 5 or 10 mins  to run.
- You could choose to make `Processlist` a class attribute, and periodically refresh Processlist using a `Timer`, by calling `Processlist = Process.GetProcesses().ToList();` on the Tick event. every 30 seconds or so while a PDF is waiting to be printed.